# What is the proper Hibernate Query for fetching data from one table based on data in another table?

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have two tables, Device contains details of a device, including if it is assigned, and CustDevice which contains additional information for devices that have been assigned to a customer.

I need to select records from the Device table if it has been assigned to a particular customer.

My first naive stab at a query was:

**from Device where Device.deviceId = CustDevice.deviceId and Device.status=2 and CustDevice.accountId=33**

That obviously does not work, but it explains the relationship I am trying to do.
I attempted to add a join in the mix, but I do not know the proper syntax for joining two tables.

I tried:

**from Device dev join dev.deviceId CustDevice where dev.deviceId = CustDevice.deviceId and dev.deviceStatus = 2 and CustDevice.accountId=33**

But that doesn't work either.
Can anyone help me out with this query??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a left join, that is all of a table plus the joined table if it is referenced.

Here is and article on left joins in Hibernate.

http://www.jairrillo.com/blog/2009/01/29/how-to-use-left-join-in-hibernate-criteria/

Comment: That didn't help much.  I was able to do "from Device dev join dev.deviceId CustDevice" before, but when I add conditions, it doesn't like that.  Also, this returns columns from both tables, not just the Device table.